# How to show that Levenshtein distance is pairwise independent

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Consider binary strings $X_1, X_2, X_3$ of maximum length $\ell$ chosen uniformly and independently at random.  Define $\operatorname{Lev}(X, Y)$ to be the [Levenshtein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) distance between two strings $X$ and $Y$.

> Is it true that $\operatorname{Lev}(X_1, X_2),
>  \operatorname{Lev}(X_2, X_3), \operatorname{Lev}(X_1, X_3)$ are pairwise independent.

And as a closely related question:

> Does it change anything if we require that the binary strings all have
>   length exactly $\ell$?

Finally:

> I believe that  $\operatorname{Lev}(X_1, X_2),
>  \operatorname{Lev}(X_2, X_3), \operatorname{Lev}(X_1, X_3)$ are not
>   mutually independent. Is that also true?

## Edit

As pointed out in the comments, my final question is trivially true because  $\operatorname{Lev}(X_1, X_2) = 0 $ and $\operatorname{Lev}(X_2, X_3) = 0$ implies $\operatorname{Lev}(X_1, X_3) = 0$.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104333/discussion-on-question-by-fomin-how-to-show-that-levenshtein-distance-is-pairwis).

Answer (score 2):

The Levenshtein distances are not independent even for strings of equal length.

Consider $\ell=3$. In this case the Levenshtein distance for all pairs is equal to the Hamming distance, except for $\operatorname{Lev}(010,101)=2$ instead of $3$. The Hamming distances are independent, and they can’t remain independent with this single modification. Indeed,

$$
P(\operatorname{Lev}(X_1,X_2)=3\cap\operatorname{Lev}(X_2,X_3)=3)=\frac6{8^3}\\\ne\frac6{8^2}\cdot\frac6{8^2}=P(\operatorname{Lev}(X_1,X_2)=3)\cdot P(\operatorname{Lev}(X_2,X_3)=3)\;.
$$

Independence doesn’t hold for strings of maximum length $\ell$, either.
Consider $\ell=2$. The strings occur different numbers of times in pairs with the maximum distance $2$: While e.g. $00$ has three strings at distance $2$ ($11$, $1$ and the empty string), $0$ only has one ($11$). Thus, $\operatorname{Lev}(X_1,X_2)=2$ means $X_2$ is more likely to be $00$ than $1$, and that in turn means that $\operatorname{Lev}(X_2,X_3)$ is more likely to be $2$ than it would be *a priori*, which contradicts independence.

Comment: Thanks so much! This is very interesting.

Comment: Thank you once more!